InvalidCNAMEError on github
I followed precisely the steps to set up DNS on Squarespece to map it to github pages:

However, I still get InvalidCNAMEError:
Both www.finestway.uk and its alternate name are improperly configured
Your site's DNS settings are using a custom subdomain, www.finestway.uk, that is not set up with a correct CNAME record. We recommend you change this to a CNAME record pointing to anatolybuga.github.io. For more information, see documentation (InvalidCNAMEError).

Checking here , my CNAME looks correct

It was just a matter of time. GitHub seems to be quite slow with resolutions. After ~half a day it worked well.
